# Rails: Convert REST API to websocket client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, websocket

I have a typical Rails REST Api written for a http consumers. However, it turns out they need web socket API because of the integration POS Machines.

The typical API looks like this;

```
class Api::Pos::V1::TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate

  def index
    @transactions = @current_business.business_account.business_deposits.last(5)
    render json: {
      status: 200,
      number: @transactions.count,
      transactions: @transactions.as_json(only: [:created_at, :amount, :status, :client_card_number, :client_phone_number])
      }

  end

  private
  def request_params
    params.permit(:account_number, :api_key)
  end

  def authenticate
      render status: 401, json: {
        status: 401,
        error: "Authentication Failed."
        }  unless current_business
  end

  def current_business
    account_number = request_params[:account_number].to_s
    api_key = request_params[:api_key].to_s
    if account_number and api_key
      account = BusinessAccount.find_by(account_number: account_number)
      if account && Business.find(account.business_id).business_api_key.token =~ /^(#{api_key})/
        @current_business = account.business
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can i serve the same responses using web-sockets?
P.S: Never worked with sockets before
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**ActionCable**

I would second Dimitris's reference to [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/actioncable), as it's expected to become part of Rails 5 and should (hopefully) integrate with Rails quite well.

Since Dimitris suggested SSE, I would recommend against doing so.

SSE (Server Sent Events) use long polling and I would avoid this technology for many reasons which include the issue of SSE connection interruptions and extensibility (websockets allow you to add features that SSE won't support).

I am almost tempted to go into a rant about SSE implementation performance issues, but... even though websocket implementations should be more performant, many of them suffer from similar issues and the performance increase is often only in thanks to the websocket connection's longer lifetime...

**Plezi**

[Plezi](http://www.plezi.io/)* is a real-time web application framework for Ruby. You can either use it on it's own (which is not relevant for you) or together with Rails.

With only minimal changes to your code, you should be able to use websockets to return results from your RESTful API. Plezi's [Getting Started Guide](http://www.plezi.io/docs/basics#our-first-http-websocket-api) has a section about unifying the backend's RESTful and Websocket API's. Implementing it in Rails should be similar.

Here's a bit of Demo code. You can put it in a file called `plezi.rb` and place it in your application's `config/initializers` folder...

Just make sure you're not using any specific Servers (thin, puma, etc'), allowing Plezi to override the server and use the Iodine server, and remember to add Plezi to your `Gemfile`.

```
  class WebsocketDemo
    # authenticate
    def on_open
      return close unless current_business
    end
    def on_message data
      data = JSON.parse(data) rescue nil
      return close unless data
      case data['msg']
      when /\Aget_transactions\z/i
        # call the RESTful API method here, if it's accessible. OR:
        transactions = @current_business.business_account.business_deposits.last(5)
        write {
        status: 200,
        number: transactions.count,
        # the next line has what I think is an design flaw, but I left it in
        transactions: transactions.as_json(only: [:created_at, :amount, :status, :client_card_number, :client_phone_number])
        # # Consider, instead, to avoid nesting JSON streams:
        # transactions: transactions.select(:created_at, :amount, :status, :client_card_number, :client_phone_number)
        }.to_json
      end
    end
    # don't disclose inner methods to the router
    protected
    # better make the original method a class method, letting you reuse it.
    def current_business
      account_number = params[:account_number].to_s
      api_key = params[:api_key].to_s
      if account_number && api_key
        account = BusinessAccount.find_by(account_number: account_number)
        if account && Business.find(account.business_id).business_api_key.token =~ /^(#{api_key})/
          return (@current_business = account.business)
        end
        false
      end
    end
  end
  Plezi.route '/(:api_key)/(:account_number)', WebsocketDemo
```

Now we have a route that looks something like: wss://my.server.com/app_key/account_number

This route can be used to send and receive data in JSON format.

To get the transaction list, the client side application can send:

```
JSON.stringify({msg: "get_transactions"})
```

This will result in data being send to the client's `websocket.onmessage` callback with the last five transactions.

Of course, this is just a short demo, but I think it's a reasonable proof of concept.

* I should point out that I'm biased, as I'm Plezi's author.

P.S.

I would consider moving the authentication into a websocket "authenticate" message, allowing the application key to be sent in a less conspicuous manner.

#### **EDIT**

These are answers to the questions in the comments.

**Capistrano**

I don't use Capistrano, so I'm not sure... but, I think it would work if you add the following line to your Capistrano tasks:

```
 Iodine.protocol = false
```

This will prevent the server from auto-starting, so your Capistrano tasks flow without interruption.

For example, at the beginning of the `config/deploy.rb` you can add the line:

```
Iodine.protocol = false
# than the rest of the file, i.e.:
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name'
#...
```

You should also edit your rakefile and add the same line at the beginning of the rakefile, so your `rakefile` includes the line:

```
Iodine.protocol = false
```

Let me know how this works. Like I said, I don't use Capistrano and I haven't tested it out.

**Keeping Passenger using a second app**

The Plezi documentation states that:

> If you really feel attached to your thin, unicorn, puma or passanger server, you can still integrate Plezi with your existing application, but they won't be able to share the same process and you will need to utilize the Placebo API (**a guide is coming soon**).

But the guide isn't written yet...

There's some information in the [GitHub Readme](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi#the-plezi-placebo-api---talking-from-afar), but it will be removed after the guide is written.

Basically you include the Plezi application with the Redis URL inside your Rails application (remember to make sure to copy all the gems used in the gemfile). than you add this line:

```
Plezi.start_placebo
```

That should be it.

Plezi will ignore the `Plezi.start_placebo` command if there is no other server defined, so you can put the comment in a file shared with the Rails application as long as Plezi's gem file doesn't have a different server.

You can include some or all of the Rails application code inside the Plezi application. As long as Plezi (Iodine, actually) is the only server in the Plezi GEMFILE, it should work.

The applications will synchronize using Redis and you can use your Plezi code to broadcast websocket events inside your Rails application.

Comment: There is one problem..Plezi does not seem to play well with Capistrano.. Kill Capistrano and hangs somewhere like this; [27b1f924]  I, [2015-11-29T18:08:57.059016 #32387]  INFO -- : Writing /var/www/html/skypay/releases/20151129230814/public/assets/transactions-ba3c52271e6b59711fbb8598fd46db7e.css
DEBUG [27b1f924]  Iodine 0.1.17 is listening on port 3000
DEBUG [27b1f924]  Press ^C to stop the server.
DEBUG [27b1f924]  Plezi is feeling optimistic running version 0.12.17.
DEBUG [27b1f924]

Comment: can i create a second app, host it as the plezi app and with in it, i only call the REST API of the main app in the plezi controllers because i like my passenger.

Comment: 1. for Capistrano, I think it would work if you add the following line to your Capistrano tasks: `Iodine.protocol = nil` ... This will prevent the server from auto-starting. 2. Yes, you can use Plezi's Placebo API or just a second app with a shared code base. The Placebo API use Redis to let you broadcast websocket events from your original application, even without a websocket connection.

Comment: please give a real example of a real capistrano last with the command

Comment: Have a look at the code posted in the following [Plezi Issue(question)](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/issues/10#issuecomment-160541702)... maybe this would help.

Comment: Also, did you make sure to edit your `rakefile` (many deployments check rake tasks as the last step in deployment)... I wish I could help you more, but it's very hard when I can't see the code and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at https://github.com/rails/actioncable which is the Rails way to deal with WebSockets, but currently in Alpha.

Judging from your code snippet, the client seems to only consume data from your backend. I'm skeptical whether you really need WebSockets. Ιf the client won't push data back to the server, [Server Sent Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) seem more appropriate.

See relevant [walk-through](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html) and [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html).

Comment: SSE uses long-polling, which blocks connections and causes repeated disconnections and reconnections. On the other hand, websocket connections often have longer lifetimes and thus use up less resources... I wouldn't recommend moving away from websockets to the older and less extensible technology of SSE unless there was a more compelling reason than the question of "who's the consumer?".